# difference between 2 arrays in php

Tags: php

I am retrieving the data from database and these values are in array format and i want to compare both arrays

```
  $u1 = "meenu1294";
  $u2 = "pr3740";
  $sql = "SELECT managers FROM users WHERE id = '$u1'";
  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
  {
     $d = $r['managers'];
   }
  $sql1 = "SELECT managers FROM users WHERE id = '$u2'";
  $res1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
  while($r1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1))
  {
     $d1 = $r1['managers'];
  }

  $x = array_diff($d,$d1);
  echo json_encode($x);
```

But it shows like

> **  Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\ofppl\sample.php on line 19 **

Give me a suggestion 
Thanks in Advance

first query field answer is `["manomhae4006","pr3740"]`

second query field answer is `["pr3740","gajaraja8196"]`

but `echo json_encode($x);` shows  `["[\"manomhae4006\",\"pr3740\"]"]`

Comment: `$d` should be `$d[]` i think and `$d1` should be `$d1[]`

Comment: And echo `$x;` will not give you nothing, array_diff() will return an array in result.

Comment: ___Big Note___ It is not really fair on those that provide you an answers if after getting an answer **you change the question !!!!!**

Comment: @RiggsFolly: agreed...

Comment: @RiggsFolly am just updating my question ya

Comment: No, you added a completely NEW issue that was not there in the original question

Comment: after your suggestion am just include what output shows to me :(

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score 2):

[`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) need both param as array and you are giving him a string.

You need to store values in an array something like:

```
$d[] = $r['managers'];
$d1[] = $r['managers'];
```

**Example:**

It's better to initiate before your `while loop` as:

```
$d = array(); // this will save empty array error.
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $d[] = $r['managers'];
}
```

And `echo $x;` will not give you nothing, `array_diff()` will return an array in result.

Side Note: Perform same activity for `$d1`

> From PHP Manual: [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) Compares array1 against one or more
>   other arrays and returns the values in array1 that are not present in
>   any of the other arrays.

**Edit:**
According to your edit, its not possible, as i check your code, its giving me this result:

```
<?php
$array1 = ["manomhae4006","pr3740"];
$array2 = ["pr3740","gajaraja8196"];
$diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($diff); // Result is Array ( [0] => manomhae4006  )

$jsonResult = json_encode($diff);
echo $jsonResult; // Result is ["manomhae4006"]
?>
```

Comment: @MeenaArumugam: i try it, and its working fine.. on my side.

Comment: Cheers for the heads up @devpro, I deleted my answer, got side tracked into a meeting so didn't see the question change :) Naughty naughty OP

Comment: @devpro i tried it , if i straightly declared like this it shows difference perfectly , but my need is from database :(

Comment: did u changed `$d` to $d[] and `$d1` as mentioned in answer and as riggsfolly suggested @MeenaArumugam

Comment: @devpro yes i changed

Comment: its a new issues @MeenaArumugam, what is the result of `print_r(array_diff($d,$d1))`;

Comment: @devpro sounds like this may have something to do with encoding

Comment: @MeenaArumugam: what is same result? what is the result of `print_r(array_diff($d,$d1))`

Comment: @devpro this is the output 

Array ( [0] => ["manomhae4006","pr3740"] )

Comment: @MeenaArumugam: `["manomhae4006","pr3740"]` and `["pr3740","gajaraja8196"]` both of them array? right??? or not??

Comment: @MeenaArumugam: share the result of `$d` and `$d1` also

Comment: I think you have found where Alice fell into the Rabbit Hole :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly: may be... but feeling tired :(

Comment: Not surprised, still cant give up now :-( ... or can you :-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly: No! waiting for response :)